# How to listen mxml event by using as3 class method?

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml

I have components in mxml and simply I want to listen these component's events from custom class methods.

I tried these;

```
list.addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_START, new CustomDragClass().DragStart);
```

error: incorrect number of arguments, Expected 1.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116532/dispatching-events-between-classes) question, Amargosh says to use `_customDragClass.DragStart` but didn't worked, too. Same error

How can I assign class method as event listener method ?

Edit: This is a working programming. I fixed the issue by **clean build project** on freakin FlashBuilder IDE.

Comment: Are constructor of CustomDragClass  expect parameter?

Comment: @AzzyElvul no it doesn't expect.

Comment: Does you DragStart function have an event type parameter?

Comment: @Pan yes, it has NativeDragEvent

Comment: Thank you guys @AzzyElvul, and Pan . clean build fixed this stupid error.